# Match with regex

Tags: open-policy-agent

Trying to figure out two issues with the below (am new to rego so this is the first time through)
I have two problems to solve, the below is only the attempt at the first.

1. validate that the input uri exists in data for this appid
2. get the object that matches the input request (not tried this, but
   mentioning in case it affects the approach to the solution #1)

I have data.json like this;

```
{
   "applications": {
        "99999-999999999999-9999999-99999": {
            "route": {
                "^/myapi/1/beans$": {
                    "GET": {
                        "bean-class": [
                            "Big beans"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "^/myapi/1/peas$": {
                    "POST": {
                        "pea-class": [
                            "Small peas"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "111111-999911111199-11111-11111": {
            "route": {
                "^/myapi/1/beans$": {
                    "GET": {
                        "bean-class": [
                            "Big beans"
                        ]
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Input is;

```
{
    "appid": "99999-999999999999-9999999-99999",
    "uri": "/myapi/1/beans"
}
```

Rego;

```
violation["route-not-found"] {
    some key
    data.applications[input.appid].route[key]
    m := has_match(key, input.uri)
    not m
}

has_match(pattern, uri) = true {
    matched := regex.match(pattern, uri)
    matched == true 
} else = false { true }
```

The above always returns false.  If I run the code within violation I can see the first 3 lines iterate the whole set of routes and show that "m" is true for the matching route.  Running all 4 lines shows that iteration stops on the match, but then the "not" triggers the violation when of course there is none.  What I can't seem to figure out is how to check all values in data and return false (false violation) when a match is found.

The second part of my question is how I can get hold of the matched object from data?  I need to do further validation on that object so need to get hold of it, not just know that it exists.  Happy if that means its in another "violation" policy, but since I had to move the regex out to a function I can't seem to get how I can get hold of the matched key?

Any thoughts?  I'm sure this is just newbie syntax issues & is just the early days of turning docs into working policies.

Update: corrected typo's

Answer (score 0):

There's some inconsistency in your shared `data.json` and the policy, which I'd assume to be a copy-edit oversight when compiling this question: data.json needs an `applications` key if you're accessing it via `data.applications[input.id]`. That `input.id` matches your `input.json`, which says `id`, not `appid`.

Those things aside, I'd start with simplifying the policy a little:

```
# returns all routes that match the app id, but not input.uri
violation[route] {
    some route
    data.applications[input.id].route[route]
    not regex.match(route, input.uri)
}
```

It's a *partial set* called violations, which will have an entry for every route in your data that **matches `input.id`** but fails to match the request path regular expression. [See this playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/SSaaQEJX61).

---

To your second question, if you want to verify further attributes of the match, it might be better to turn this upside down into an **allow** rule: the request will only be allowed if there is a matching rule in data, for the app id in question:

```
allow = extra {
    some route
    request := data.applications[input.id].route[route]
    regex.match(route, input.uri)
    extra := request[input.method] # fails if request doesn't have a such a key
}
```

[See this playground.](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/BxaoYUVW14)

Note that I've only added `allow = extra` for illustration, an ordinary `allow` rule would do:

```
allow {
  # ...
}
```

Comment: yes, thanks for the response.  Copy/paste issues - sigh!  I think perhaps I didn't explain the question properly.
What I want is effectively an allow=false response from the policy when the URI requested doesn't exist for the appid.  So {  "appid": "99999-.........", "uri": "/myapi/1/beansXXX"  }
Would return false (the 2nd playground returns undefined) {}.

I get the point in the 1st playground, but same point, I would want the partial set to contain the input.uri that doesn't exist for that input.appid within data.applications, or just "false" in that case.

Comment: Try adding `default allow = false`